# Retrieve multilple objects from multiple categories (many-to-many rel) more djangoish way

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I am developing a newslettersystem. In this system there are Newslettercategories and Newsletterabos (speak subscriptions) which have a many to many relation.
Consider these two models:

```
class NewsletterCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['title']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class NewsletterAbo(models.Model):
    abo_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(NewsletterCategory, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=['last_name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.last_name + ', ' +self.first_name)
```

Now imagine that i want to sent out a Newsletter to multiple NewsletterCategories without newsletters beeing sent to one emailadress multiple times. This could happen if one NewsletterAbo is in multiple NewsletterCategories.
So far I gather the Abos I want to send mails to similiar to this (avoiding duplicates):

```
# get all NewsletterCategories that are active, 
categories = NewsletterCategory.objects.filter(is_active=True)
# initialize empty list for storing NewsletterAbos
abolist = []
# loop through retrieved NewsLetterCategories
for cat in categories:
    # get NewsletterAbos that are related to a NewsletterCategory
    abos = cat.newsletterabo_set.filter(is_active=True)
    # add retrieved NewsletterAbos to list
    abolist += abos
# removing duplicate entries
abolist = set(abolist)

# ... do something else then like sending out newsletter to abolist subscriptions
```

Abolist is now a list of abolist items without duplicates.
My Question is: Is there a more "django-ish" way of doing this, using the ORM.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
With help of lazerscience answer i figured out the following code which suits my needs:

```
qs=NewsletterAbo.objects.filter(categories__is_active=True, 
                                categories__id__in=[1,2,3,4], 
                                is_active=True).distinct()
```

This line of code retrieves all NewsletterAbos which I need. The new qs stores that list (it is a queryset to be honest) of abo items i had formerly stored in abolist.

Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the email to send the newsletter to, you could do it like this:

```
qs = NewsletterAbo.objects.filter(categories_set__is_active=True)
qs = qs.values_list('email', flat=True).distinct()
```

This will give you a flat list of unique email addresses while hitting the database only once. 
Have a look at the django documentation for more information on [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)/[`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list).